# OpenRecord.js ActiveRecord RAW or Complex SQL QUERIES

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js, openrecord.js

When you use repo `"openrecord": "^2.11.1"` for your connection to MySql and you need join or do complex queries and you stack! How I'can do that?

https://openrecord.js.org/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Openrecord** use **knex** to connect and internal queries you can access to do queries

How? Like this:

```
const cfg = {
    db:{
        database: '',
        user: '',
        password: '',

        type: 'mysql',
        autoConnect: true,
        autoLoad: true
    }
};

const store = require('openrecord/store/mysql')(cfg.db);

const query = await store.connection.raw('SELECT * FROM a.`table` JOIN b.`table` ON(a.`id`=b.`id`) WHERE a.`active`=1');

console.log(query[0]); //this return array of objects
```

That's it! Maybe this solve your problem.

Comment: Well the question is Did it solve Your problem, as you also asked the question?

Comment: I quested, and I find the solution... XD